# Angular 9 - Webpack how does Chrome DevTools decide which folders to watch?

Tags: angularjs, webpack, google-chrome-devtools

In an `Angular 9` application I have 2 projects such as `angular.json`:

```
{
  //some config...
  "projects": {
    "mainProject": {//some config...},
    "custom-charts-lib": {//some config...}
  }
}
```

In development mode I end up with the following source map bundled by `webpack` :

[image]

I can debug as usual the `src/` folder but any breakpoints I put in `projects/custom-charts-lib/src/lib` are ignored.

How does Google Chrome DevTools decide which folders to watch for breakpoints ? Does there is a way to add this folder to the "watch folders" or a webpack trick to make it work ?

Comment: Check that this script is not blackboxed

Comment: @PetrAveryanov sorry but what does blackboxed means ?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/blackboxing -- The debugger will not pause on any breakpoints set in library code.

Comment: I did not specify blackboxing patterns in the debugger :/